# rglob to batch convert CSVs to TSVs

Tags: python

I have a folder of hundreds of CSVs that I need to convert to TSV for Postgres upload.

I wrote this script, but nothing seems to happen when I run it.  Can anyone see what the issue is?

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pathlib

for file in pathlib.Path().rglob('*.csv'):
    with open(file,'r') as csvin, open(file + ".tsv", 'w') as tsvout:
        csvin = csv.reader(csvin)
        tsvout = csv.writer(tsvout, delimiter='\t')

        for row in csvin:
            tsvout.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Please try debugging using a debugger or print statements to see which statements aren't being executed, then update the question

Comment: What's in `pathlib.Path().rglob('*.csv')` ?

Comment: When I print that command it returns this: `<generator object Path.rglob at 0x11044f620>`

Comment: Passing a Path instance to open() should crash, which would imply that rglob() is empty. You should either be converting the Path instance to a string, or else calling Path.open().

Comment: I don't think that's it because when I had both the read and write file vars set to `file`, it overwrote all my original files as zero bytes.  Which makes me think it can at least find the files.  Now I just need to figure out how to incrementally alter the output file name so it doesn't overwrite.

Comment: As an aside, I’m 99% sure Postgres can handle CSV files.

Comment: Add a print statement to print the filenames...looks like maybe it is iterating through an empty list for some reason.

Comment: @soundstripe - it can, but when you have cells with strings that contain commas, the comma delimiter will split those, then throw an error bc you have more columns than expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing pandas...you could try:

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pathlib

for file in pathlib.Path().rglob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.from_csv(str(file))
    df.to_csv(str(file.with_name(file.stem + ‘.csv’)), sep=‘\t’)
```